# Hibernate OnDelete Cascade not working for MySql but Works on postgres and Ms-Sql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-cascade

I'm having 2 Entities. **Thread** entity and **Post** entity using OnetoOne mapping from **Post->Thread.**

A **Thread** entity contains Numerous **Posts**. I know i should have used OnetoMany instead of OnetoOne, but for avoiding all the Collections problems i'm using OnetoOne

Now the problem is, when i delete a **Thread**, all the **post** associated with it must also be removed.
I'm successful in doing it by using

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

But it works only on Postgres and Ms-SQl but not on MySql(Tried InnoDb as well). The **on delete cascade** is not generated in the schema generation query.

Following are the code

```
//Thread Entity
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "thread_id")
private int ThreadID;
```

---

```
//Post Entity
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "post_id")
private int PostID;

@OneToOne()
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private thread ThreadID;
```

I get the following error While deleting an item from **Thread** entity using the following query

```
session.delete(session.load(thread.class,1));
```

> Sep 02, 2014 8:33:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
>   Sep 02, 2014 8:33:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forum`.`post_tbl`, CONSTRAINT `FK_bfbv5nknqj7ppd5630scimhtb` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadID_thread_id`) REFERENCES `thread_tbl` (`thread_id`))
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3343)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3546)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:293)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
>       at test.main(test.java:84)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forum`.`post_tbl`, CONSTRAINT `FK_bfbv5nknqj7ppd5630scimhtb` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadID_thread_id`) REFERENCES `thread_tbl` (`thread_id`))
>   HibernateException : could not execute statement
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
>       ... 14 more
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Please help me find a way out of this.

Answer (score 14):

This is what I did to resolve this problem based on Spring Boot.

**Solution**

from

```
// application.properties  
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

to

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**Explanation**
As you can see below, it seems like the default value for CascadeDelete at MySQL5InnoDBDialect.java only support Cascade.

```
// MySQLDialect.java
@Override
    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }

// MySQL5InnoDBDialect.java
@Override
    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Lost hours hunting down this problem. CascadeType does not work, you need to specifically use @OnDelete plus the dialect is wrong. Combination of these two fixes worked for me.

Comment: @cen
Sure, you need @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) on field and I don't follow "the dialect is wrong", can you please give me more detail which dialect is wrong?

Comment: I was just confirming your solution about changing the dialect.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were talking about me when you said "you need to,,," alright never mind.

Comment: FYI if you created DB tables from JPA entities with old dialect, you would need to regenerate them with new dialect. Otherwise your existing DB constraints do not let you remove entities even with new dialect set on the server.